# How to read data from HashMap in main program into another class

Tags: java

This is my main code. I am trying to design a room reservation system, so I use HashMap to get my roomlist.

```
import java.util.*;


public class MiniProject {

private static Scanner inp = null;

public static void main(String[] args) {

        Reservation person = null;
        inp = new Scanner( System.in );  //input

        System.out.println( "Welcome to the Room Reservation System" );
        System.out.print( "Username: " );
        String name = inp.nextLine(); 

        String admin = "admin";
        if(name.equals(admin))
        {
             Admin a = new Admin(name);
             System.out.print("Enter password: ");
             String password=inp.nextLine();
             a.checkPassword(password);
        }
    else
        {
            person = new Reservation(name);
            System.out.println();
        }

    HashMap<String, Integer> room = new HashMap<>();


    room.put("Lecture Room 1", 1);
    room.put("Lecture Room 2", 2);
    room.put("Lecture Room 3", 3);
    room.put("Lecture Room 4", 4);
    room.put("Lecture Room 5", 5);
    room.put("Lecture Room 6", 6);
    room.put("Lecture Room 7", 7);
    room.put("Lecture Room 8", 8);
    room.put("Lecture Room 9", 9);
    room.put("Lecture Room 10", 10);
    room.put("Lecture Hall 1", 11);
    room.put("Lecture Hall 2", 12);
    room.put("Lecture Hall 3", 13);
    room.put("Lecture Hall 4", 14);
    room.put("Lecture Hall 5", 15);
    room.put("Lecture Hall 6", 16);
    room.put("Lecture Hall 7", 17);
    room.put("Lecture Hall 8", 18);
    room.put("Lecture Hall 9", 19);
    room.put("Lecture Hall 10", 20);
    room.put("Computer Training Lab 1", 21);
    room.put("Computer Training Lab 2", 22);
    room.put("Computer Training Lab 3", 23);
```

Have I correctly created the available room?

I want to use the room in another class call RoomChecker so I can check availability of the room. all room is initially empty. The interger value is meant to be an id. So if system book the number, room will become unavailable. but how do I read the roomlist in my RoomChecker class?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you understand the differences between **local variables** and **instance variables (or fields)** as well as objects and data encapsulation in Java. There are plenty good examples out in the web. It is also good practice not to write everything in your main method, but in several methods which are named by the thing they do (e.g. fillRoomsWithData()).

To your specific problem: Declare Map rooms in your class MiniProject (note the plural in the name). After creation of a RoomChecker instance you can pass the rooms to it (read about Setter first). From there you can access the values you passed in before.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the `HashMap` in another class, just make it available to the class. An example would be to initialize the `RoomChecker` class with the `HashMap` so that it can use all of the variables within.

```
public class RoomChecker {

   HashMap<String,Integer> rooms;

   public RoomChecker(HashMap<String,Integer> rooms)
   {
      this.rooms = rooms;
   }

   //... Other methods to perform stuff on the rooms

   public boolean hasRoom(String roomName)
   {
      return rooms.containsKey(roomName);
   }

   public boolean hasRoom(Integer roomNumber)
   {
      return rooms.containsValue(roomNumber);
   }
   //... etc
}
```

I think the best approach of what you are wanting to accomplish though is to have a seperate class `Room` that has several fields such as `boolean occupied`, `int roomNumber`, `String roomName` and such, and make an `ArrayList` of rooms instead of `HashMap`

Answer (score 0):

I think, you should start with somethink easier. But if you need to create reservation system, you should create class `Room` with fields

`int id;
string name; 
bool reserved`,

getters and setters and methods 
`bool isReserved();`

In `SystemReservation` class you should create `arraylist` which contains objects of class `Room`.